# Finding the confidence interval for linear prediction: Numpy multiplication error

Tags: python, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I have the data matrix `X`, which I fit to the linear model, in particular `ransac = linear_model.RANSACRegressor()`.

I find the coefficients to be:
`coef = ransac.estimator_.coef_`

Now, I am trying to find the confidence interval for my predictions, so I need to calculate:
[image]

This should always be positive, however, after calculating:

```
c = np.ones(X.shape[2]) # a vector of ones
XTX = np.matmul(np.transpose(np.matrix(X)), np.matrix(X))
# find the bit inside square root
np.matmul( np.matmul(np.transpose(c),np.linalg.inv(XTX) ) ,  c.reshape((c.shape[0],1)) )
```

However, this is a negative value, which should not even be possible... How do I go around this problem?

Step by step breakdown:

```
c = X[0]
c = np.reshape(c , (c.shape[0],1))
ct = np.reshape(c , (1, c.shape[0]))
XTX = np.matmul(np.transpose(np.matrix(X)), np.matrix(X))
XTXinv = np.linalg.inv(XTX)
XTXinvc = np.matmul(XTXinv, c)
ctXTXinvc = np.matmul(ct, XTXinvc)
# ctXTXinvc is negative
```

Comment: I realised that the `c` is not actually coefficients, and should be replaced by `np.ones` e.g. `c=np.ones(X.shape[1])` if I want to include all predictors, but it's still giving me a negative value

Comment: ..and your code looks a bit messy. It is always a good practice to separate computations into meaningful variables, this helps debugging a lot. Try it out !

Comment: @mctrjalloh I must say the reshapes are particularly annoying, because after matmuling matrices pxp and px1, I'd expect the product to be px1, not 1xp